# How to statistically determining a suitable sample size when population SD is unknown

Tags: r, self-study, statistical-significance, sample-size

I have a data set which contains data about mobile phone testing. They inspect the phones for their quality (health effects for people) and give a score between 0 and 100 (0 being unhealthy for usage and 100 being perfectly fine). They inspect phones previously found to be in poor condition more often, and inspect those previously found to be in good condition less often. Therefore each year the sample size they chose is different. For example in 2000-01 645 phones were inspected and in 20001-02, 2002-03 and 2003-04 2587, 3500 and 1657 phones were analysed respectively. **As the sample sizes vary significantly I need to find the most suitable sample size for the analysis and exclude the years which have less or more**. (Please note that population size or SD is unknown)

I’m doing my analysis using R however I’m **looking for a theoretical answer** as I can’t share the data. Thank you.

Below is a set of sample data values:

```
PhoneID Year PhoneType Manufacturer Score
1 2000-01 N123  Nokia   90
2 2000-01 S345 Samsung 30
3 2000-01 I789 Apple 35
2 2001-02 S345 Samsung 70
3 2001-02 I789 Apple 37
2 2002-03 S345 Samsung 75
3 2002-03 I789 Apple 16
1 2002-03 N123 Nokia 95
```

This is the boxplot for the variation in scores over the inspection duration. 
[image]

**Update:**
Some of the questions are;

1. How does the sample size vary over the years? Are there any years that should exclude (Justify your answer)?
2. How does the condition of the phones change over time? (Assumption: data is a representation of the sample)
3. What are the significant phone brands and why? Is the current sampling method suitable to obtain the information required?
4. Is the company running sufficient number of tests?

Comment: The scores in the sample data shown, are for individual phones, yes? Then you can estimate the SD from the data you have. The sample sizes seems to be large, so estimated SD's should be good.  And, what are the questions you are asking from the data, that you want to be answered by analyzing the data? proportion of phones (of each make/year combination) that have "acceptable score", for some def of "acceptable"? If there is a trend in the scores? If there is significant difference between Phonetypes/Manufacturers? ... You must tell us!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes the scores are for individual phones. There was no mention about the acceptable score though. I have added few questions above. My main question is as mentioned above, what is the most suitable sample size for the analysis?

Comment: Which analysis? You did not spcify!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I updated the question including some of the sample questions I have to answer. I'm mainly looking the answer for the first question . In order to determine a sample size do I need to have a specific  analysis objective?